# How to create a generalized JavaScript function that can run python scripts and return data in json format if any?

Tags: javascript, python, child-process

### What I am currently able to do

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

exports.fetchWeatherdata = (location) => {
  console.log("DIR NAME DB" + __dirname)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let buf = "";
    const python = spawn("python", [
      __dirname + "/weathergetter.py",
      location.toString(),
    ]);

    python.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      buf += data;
    });

    python.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
      console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
    });

    python.on("close", (code) => {
      if (code !== 0) {
        return reject(`child process died with ${code}`);
      }
      const dataToSend = JSON.parse(buf.toString().replace(/\'/g, '"'));
      return resolve(dataToSend);
    });
  });
};


//in another file
const { fetchWeatherdata } = require('../python/weather')
exports.sendData = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query)
    console.log(req.params)

    async function main() {
        var wea = await fetchWeatherdata(req.params.loc);
        // console.log(wea);
        res.send(wea)
    }
    main()
}
```

### What I want to achieve

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

exports.pythonFileRunner = (pathToFile, arguments) => {
   // some code goes here. This is where I need help
   return "output of the python file "
}

//in another file
const { pythonFileRunner } = require('../python/weather')

exports.fetchWeatherdata = (location) => {
   //something like this ↓↓↓
   data = pythonFileRunner("path/to/file/main.py", location)
   return data
}
```

Basically, I want to create a function that can run any given python file with or without arguments and return its output.
**Please Note**: I want to finish all the `async-await` stuff inside the `pythonFileRunner()` function. This function must return only the output, which I can modify according to my usecase

If I am taking the wrong approach, please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the fetchweatherdata function little to get what I wanted.

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

function pythonRunner(path, arguments) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let buf = "";
        arguments.unshift(path)
        const python = spawn("python", arguments);
    
        python.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
          buf += data;
        });
    
        python.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
          console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
        });
    
        python.on("close", (code) => {
          if (code !== 0) {
            return reject(`child process died with ${code}`);
          }
          const dataToSend = buf
          return resolve(dataToSend);
        });
      });
}



//in any other file
//first import the function

//how to use the function
(async () => {
  data = await pythonRunner("path/to/python/file", ["arg1", "arg2"])
  console.log(data)
})()
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be basically the same. Just replace

```
    const python = spawn("python", [
      __dirname + "/weathergetter.py",
      location.toString(),
    ]);
```

with

```
    const python = spawn("python", [
      pathToFile,
      ...arguments
    ]);
```

Comment: I want to finish all the async await stuff inside the pythonFileRunner() function. This function must return only the output, which I can modify according to my usecase

Comment: If you copy the rest of the code from `fetchWeatherData()` it will do that.

Comment: Can you please show how

Comment: can you help with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353434/how-to-run-python-script-as-global-command-from-any-terminal-instance-similar-to)

Comment: I know how to do it on Linux, I don't know Windows.

Comment: is it different, I think I have to work with environment variables or similar stuff.

Comment: I don't know, since I don't know Windows very well.

Comment: It's whatever is equivalent to the `$PATH` environment variable, maybe `%PATH%`? And start the script with the Windows equivalent of `#!/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: ok,  no problem.

Comment: Can you help with this Javascriptcript question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810943/problem-when-using-async-await-block-inside-then-block-in-javascript-nodejs)