# How to run python script as global command from any terminal instance similar to pip or howdoi command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, environment-variables

### Problem to solve

I have a python script called `myscript.py` in a directory.
To run `myscript.py`, I have to open terminal in the same directory and do `python myscript.py` or `python path_to_the_py_file`

### What I want to achieve

I can open a instance of terminal anywhere, anytime and do `myscript` or `myscript arguments -options`. By doing this, I should be able to run the script.

I want to implement something like `pip` command or the [`howdoi`](https://github.com/gleitz/howdoi) package.

When I enter `myscript` in terminal I should not get:

 `myscript: The term 'myscript' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

If you have any confusion please ask in comments. if the title needs improvement, feel free to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be quite a few things in this question.

First, you want to make you file executable.

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/script.py
```

Then, since this is an interpreted language, you’ll have to specify the interpreter in a shebang at the top of the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

OR

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Finally, you’ll have to put it in your PATH environment variable, which can be done in a variety of ways, simplest might be symlink in ~/bin or ~/.local/bin, depending on what you have.

Also, this will make script.py available as an executable, you can rename it or rename its symlink to just script if you don’t want .py.

Comment: where to find `bin` folder

Comment: I just realise you tagged this for Windows and I replied for *nix.  

I don’t remember off the top of my head the Windows process, so instead I found you this [page](https://correlated.kayako.com/article/40-running-python-scripts-from-anywhere-under-windows).  

I have not tested it and you should make sure you understand what the instructions you’ll be running do, but hopefully that points you in the right direction.