# Problem when using async-await block inside .then() block in javascript-nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, async.js

**Problem**:
I am using ipManager as a middleware. But due to some reason the the same json object is getting added to firestore two times. Also, many other lines are getting repeated.
**Code:**

```js
//imports...
exports.ipManager = (req, res, next) => {
  const ip = req.clientIp;
  const fullUrl = req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host") + req.originalUrl;
  console.log(fullUrl)
  if ((ip == "::1") & req.get("host").includes("localhost")) {
    console.log(
      "[+] ipManager functionalities restricted due to server running in local machine"
    );
    console.info(`[+] method=GET path=${fullUrl}`);
    next();
    return;
  }
  const _URL = req.originalUrl
  if (_URL.includes("documentation") || _URL.includes("weather") || _URL=="/") {
    console.log(_URL)
  } else {
    next()
    return
  }

  console.log("IP address " + ip);
  axios
    .get(`http://ip-api.com/json/${ip}`)

    // Show response data
    .then((res) => {
      const info = res.data;
      console.info(JSON.stringify(res.data));
      (async () => {
        try {
          const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "req_info_2022.1.22"), {
            country: info.country,
            countryCode: info.countryCode,
            region: info.region,
            regionName: info.regionName,
            city: info.city,
            zip: info.zip,
            lat: info.lat,
            lon: info.lon,
            timezone: info.timezone,
            isp: info.isp,
            org: info.org,
            as: info.as,
            ip: info.query,
            path: fullUrl,
          });
          console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
        }
      })()
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

  next();
};
```

**This is the console log statements:**
Note: Observe that the console.logs are getting repeated two times. Due to this, two documents(which are same) are getting saved in the firebase collection.
[image: application logs]

**Forec HTTPS middleware**

```js
'use strict';
exports.redirectToHTTPS = (req,res,next) => {
  var schema = (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || '').toLowerCase();
  if (req.headers.host.indexOf('localhost')<0 && schema!=='https') {
    res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please feel free to generalize the question

Comment: Ahhh, the dreaded `(async () => { })();`.  Don't do it.  Don't do it.  It causes problems.  It's an async function that returns a promise and you do NOTHING with that promise.  So, no wonder it's completely disconnected from anything else in your program flow or error handling.  Nothing waits for that promise to be done before proceeding.  Nothing handles any errors if that promise rejects.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you please add an answer with the correct code, the correct way to implement what I have done

Comment: If I had any idea what you were really trying to accomplish here, I might be able to write an answer.  I can just see something that is clearly wrong so I pointed it out.

Comment: @jfriend00 if I don't use the async block, I am not able to log the doc.id

Comment: @jfriend00 Should I use it as a separate function, or should I instead use .then().
More, importantly, why is very thing happening twice

Comment: I can't follow your logs, but is this function just getting called more than once?  If so, what is the output from `console.log(fullUrl)` each time it's called?  And, can you show the code where this function is registered as middleware.  You need to add enough logging that you can see why this is getting called when it is.

Comment: @CuriousLearner There is nothing in the code above that indicates why this block is executing twice. The cause of double-execution is outside this code, i.e. it is in the code that calls this code.

Comment: It looks like the route that handles this URL `http://weatherdbi.herokuapp.com/data/weather/london`  is calling this function twice.  We can't tell if your server is getting two separate requests for that URL or if you have some problem upstream of this function in the server that causes it to call this function twice.  But, the "twice" problem is upstream from the code you show.  Also, it's completely unclear from this code how you expect to not have duplicates in the database since its perfectly normal for the same route to get called more than once over time.

Comment: @jfriend00 In the entry file called `index.js`, I have `app.use(ipManager)`. I am using `Express.js`

Comment: Add this as your very first middleware: `app.use((req, res, next) =>{console.log("incoming:", req.url); next();});`.  If you see this logged twice for the same URL in quick succession, then the problem is coming from your client and you'd have to show the relevant client code for us to have any idea what's happening there.  If this only logs once for each URL, then somehow your server code is calling `ipManager` twice for each request.

Comment: @jfriend00 Before `ipManager` I have another middleare that forces https connection by redirecting, to https(which causes no prpoblem). But, this "happening twice" issue started today, when I put my `try-catch` block inside the `async` block so that I can get the `docReff.id` which was previously showing undefined without the presence the `async` block. Please read the title of the question. I think the issue is related to that, which I am not able to solve

Comment: Well, that was my original comment here.   Get rid of the `(async () => { })();` block and add async to the parent `.then(async (res) => {...})`.  Get your `async` from there, not from the AIIFE.  I don't personally understand how that has anything to do with duplicate requests, but you can at least fix that first problem I saw.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, I will try this out. Thanks for your advice. Hope this will work

Comment: In reality, you should just switch everything to `async/await` so you're not mixing that with `.then()` and `.catch()`.  A mixed model is much harder to do things correctly.

Comment: https://weatherdbi.herokuapp.com <br><br>
By the way, this is a  new api for fetching free weather data for any specified location. Just replace {location} with `london`,  `newyork`, `California`, etc.
No signup required, no api key required. 7-days prediction, detailed weather data for today.  Soon, historical data, precipitation prediction ---features are comming

Comment: And, your code is calling `next()` BEFORE any of your asynchronous operations in here are done.  Not sure if that matters, but it is usually not how you want it to work.

Comment: @jfriend00 So, I will make the whole function `async`. And remove the `.then()` syntax

Comment: If your middleware that forces https is calling `next()` (which continues routing), then that could explain the duplicate.  When you call `res.redirect()`, you should NOT be calling `next()` in that same code flow.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have checked. `next()` is not in the `res.redirect()` code block.

Comment: Well, I think we've established that the offending code is not shown in your question so we can't really help further without seeing more code, either the https redirect code, all other middleware code or the client code.

Comment: @jfriend00 You might want to vote to close then

Comment: @Bergi - Well, I was hoping to shepherd the OP to include the relevant code.  But, if they don't, then closing is appropriate.

Comment: @CuriousLearner Is your issue resolved? I see there is an answer below. If yes, please acknowledge the answer. If no, please let me know the error you are getting.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra the problem is not yet solved. But the code in the answer is much cleaner than my code and so I have modified the code, according to my needs. But again, the problem is not solved.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing now? Please edit the question and include the new error.

Comment: Hi @CuriousLearner if you could help me with the details, I will try to help you with a solution. Please let us know if the issue is not solved yet and what is the error you are receiving while trying to execute the code?